# Playing HTML 5 video from Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template

I want to start playing a HTML video programmatically from TypeScript when the User clicks on the Video area itself.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="video">
<video controls (click)="toggleVideo()" id="videoPlayer">
    <source src="{{videoSource}}" type="video/mp4" />
    Browser not supported
</video>
</div>
```

This is my TypeScript code:

```
@ViewChild('videoPlayer') videoplayer: any;

toggleVideo(event: any) {
    this.videoplayer.play();
}
```

The issue is that I get an error that says `play()` function is not defined/exists. What could be the mistake here?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Problem is you're trying to get a reference to `video` element using its `id`. You need to use **template reference variable** (`#`) instead:

```
<div class="video">
    <video controls (click)="toggleVideo()" #videoPlayer>
        <source src="{{videoSource}}" type="video/mp4" />
        Browser not supported
    </video>
</div>
```

Read more about template reference variable [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars).

Edit:

Also, in your `toggleVideo(event: any)` function, you need to get `nativeElement` and then call the `play()` function because you are accessing DOM element directly:

```
@ViewChild('videoPlayer') videoplayer: ElementRef;

toggleVideo(event: any) {
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();
}
```

Credits to @peeskillet for this one.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I am still getting an exception that was reads `this.videoplayer.play is not a function`.

Comment: @Rai Are you sure `video` has `play` function?

Comment: I think you need to get the native element from the elementRef. video is standard html. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

Comment: Yeah, @peeskillet is totally right. Try `this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();`.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota Yes. I am able to call the `play()` function from DOM itself. But can't call the same function from Typescript.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota @peeskillet It worked! `this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();` works perfectly. But I have no idea what this `nativeElement` is about or how to use it.

Comment: @Rai it's the DOM element

Comment: @peeskillet I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thought this might prove helpful for others on this post... toggle pause and play inside of the toggleVideo function: ```this.videoplayer.nativeElement.paused ? this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play() : this.videoplayer.nativeElement.pause();```

Comment: I have multiple video. but play single video only . how to platy it

Comment: In my case it's list of video(like facebook) how to get native element in that case

Comment: Chrome has changed the autoplay policy, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes. To work in chrome make the video mute before playing.

Comment: is it possible to play video on hover without use of typescript code?

Comment: @StefanSvrkota : sir its working with mp4 format so how to play avi and wmv video type ?

Comment: You need to add mute  const media = this.videoplayer.nativeElement;
    media.muted = true; // without this line it's not working although I have "muted" in HTML
    media.play();

Answer (score 11):

Others have already answered the basic question (you must use `nativeElement`). However, since `nativeElement` is of type `any` you should 'cast' it to a more specific element type (for the `<video>` tag this is `HTMLVideoElement`).

```
 const video: HTMLVideoElement = this.videoElement.nativeElement;
 video.play();
```

This then gives you intellisense for all the supported methods and properties.

And of course this is all just compile time - you're not converting anything and you'll still get an error if the element is not really a video.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the correct Types. Important to note that HTMLVideoElement is the type of the ElementRef.nativeElement of a video tag.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another way to set your `videoPlayer` variable to use `HTMLVideoElement` for type safety

```
videoPlayer: HTMLVideoElement;

@ViewChild('videoPlayer')
  set mainVideoEl(el: ElementRef) {
    this.videoPlayer = el.nativeElement;
  }

toggleVideo(event: any) {
    this.videoplayer.play();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my HTML code:

```
  <video controls class="video" (play)="video()" autoplay #videoPlayer>
    <source src="assets/video/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

This is my TS code:

```
  @ViewChild('videoPlayer') videoplayer: ElementRef;

  video() {
    console.log('im Play!');
    this.videoplayer?.nativeElement.play();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how I did it:

```
<video (click)="playVideo($event)">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

TS

```
playVideo(event) {
   event.toElement.play()
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation of why this works.

Remember, your answers aren't just for the original question (which is now over 3 years old), but for future readers who have the same problem.

Comment: If you console.log($event) you'll see that toElement is the clicked element which is <video>.
And play() is a  function to play the video!

 did you down voted my answer because of that?

Comment: so this does work however pausing the video does not seem to work