# HTML dont run video on localhost

Tags: html, webpack

i want to add a simple video to my project. I work with aurelia as front-end and webpack. When i open the video in basic html file (not on localhost) the video works perfectly, but when i enter the same code into my project video dont loads.

my webpack.config file looks like this

```json
{
  test: /\.(mov|mp4)$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        outputPath: "src/"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

html where i want to load the video looks like this

```html
<video width="500" height="350" controls playsinline autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="../dalifinal2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

The src path is okay. i dont know what the problem is thank you

Comment: Is your video correctly located on ```../dalifinal2.mp4``` from your HTML file on your localhost?

Comment: yes it is https://imgur.com/GOs6D2C here is picture and it gives me suggestion so am sure it is yes

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the right directory, please try with this `<source src="dalifinal2.mp4" type="video/mp4">` because your movie is in the `/src` root directory

Comment: GET http://localhost:8080/dalifinal2.mp4  this is what i get i think its may not uploaded on the host ?

Comment: You need to add HTML Video type to your webApp like in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360174/playing-html-5-video-from-angular-2-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

**../** points the URL one directory back, so let's say if your HTML file is in

```
 localhost/html/index.html
```

and using this code the video should be in

```
localhost/dalifinal2.mp4
```

if you want your video in the same directory as your HTML file then omit **../**

Answer (score -1):

change your code `Your browser does not support HTML5 video.`  TO `Your browser does not support the video tag.` as shown below and try again

```
    <video width="500" height="350" controls playsinline autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="../dalifinal2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

*MAKE SURE YOUR VIDEO SRC IS POINTING TO THE RIGHT URL*

Comment: Hello kelvin, thank you the message isnt show and yes the video src is pointing to the right url https://imgur.com/GOs6D2C

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: @boris make sure your browser supports HTML 5 or try a different project because the code i posted over here is working well in my project.

Comment: its working on my if its not uploaded on a localhost as well. i wonder if i need to encode video or do some stuff on the localhost. Staticaly on desktop is working fine but when i try to add to my project who is built with webpack the video doesnt work