# How to play a video in background on clicking button in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I was trying to make quiz application where there are 4 buttons as options, if someone click on correct option one video will be played on background then after video got over,a modal will appear showing about play again or exit.same occurs in choosing wrong answer.How can i solve this in angular?

```
if (op == this.f) {
      $('#dv').show();
      this.videoplayer1.nativeElement.play();
      $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('toggle');
    } else {
      $('#dv1').show();
      this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();
      $('#exampleModalCenter1').modal('toggle');
    }
```

i have improved the code done with video part but here my modal and video appearing simultaneously how can i delay the modal so that it should appear after video gets over..

Comment: you can add 4 buttons (button component), and add a `<video>` in background (backgroundVideo component). and bind buttons `(click)` events to a function to set the `src` parameter of the video component to a path of video file, and set the `isPlaying` of it to true. (for put the video to background, you can use css. for playing and setting the src of video, you can use html5 video tag.)

Comment: thank you but i did not get that how can it be played??...coz if i will use autoplay function in <video> then it plays automatically without clicking any button...how can i control it in TS

Comment: you can get the dom element of the `<video>` tag by `viewChild`, then you can control the video by the dom methods (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp). more details about play video in angular:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360174/playing-html-5-video-from-angular-2-typescript also note that it's better to find a npm package for video player in angular.

Comment: thank you so much i have set the video and it is working perfectly now the problem is my modal and video are appearing in same time how can i sort that modal will appear after video got over??if (op == this.f) {
      //console.log('galat hai');
      $('#dv').show();
      this.videoplayer1.nativeElement.play();
      $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('toggle');
    } else {
      //console.log('sahi hai');
      $('#dv1').show();
      this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();
      $('#exampleModalCenter1').modal('toggle');
    }

Comment: you can handle the events of video tag (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp) and show/hide the modal on that handlers.